# Include links that jump to specific times in a Youtube Player within WordPress

Tags: javascript, youtube, wordpress

Within a **self-hosted WordPress** blog post, I'm trying to share a Youtube video, and then have **links also within that** post that tell the player to **jump to specific times**. WordPress strips JavaScript from links, which would be the easy way to control the player. Such as:

```
<a href="javascript:player.seekTo(60,true)">1:00</a>
```

YouTube JavaScript reference
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Is there a simple plugin that enables this? Is there some specific way for me to format JavaScript so that it will not be stripped from a blog post?

Further example use...

```
[myvideo]

Link to 1:11
Link to 2:22
Link to 5:55
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too simplistic a method, but since Youtube allows links like: http://youtu.be/g_FEVa75H8g?t=2m36s

would it not be easier just to link the times manually?

e.g. Link to 1:11 would be http://youtu.be/g_FEVa75H8g?t=1m11s

Comment: That would open a link to the video on youtube, whereas I am thinking to make an embedded video jump in time. Click > Embedded video jumps to time > Scroll browser back to video if necessary.

Comment: I see where you're coming from now - thanks for the clarification. @brasofilo seems to have a much better suggestion/answer below then :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the other API reference: [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), just like the `[myvideo]` you're already using.

It would be like `[videolinks times="60,150,230" showtimes="1m,2m30s,3m50s"]`.

And the shortcode code:

```
add_shortcode( 'videolinks', 'my_shortcode_handler' );

function my_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null )
{
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    $times = explode( ',', $atts['times'] );
    $showtimes = explode( ',', $atts['showtimes'] );
    foreach( $times as $time )
    {
        $output .= sprintf(
            '<a href="javascript:player.seekTo(%s,true)">Link to %s</a><br />',
            $time,
            $showtime[$count]
        );
        $count++;
    }
    return $output;
}
```